# Syntax Error in MS Query Builder

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, query-builder

I'm creating a parameterized query in Excel 2010 to get data from an Access 2010 database (data does reside in Access).

This is the query in Access:

```
SELECT [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].[Pt Comp ID], [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Date,
       [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Gender, [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Age, 
       [Group Type].Description, Nz([Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].[Pt Dept ID],'EMPLOYEE') AS DeptID, 
       [App Type].Description AS [App Type], [Group Type].[Sort Order], [App Type].Provider, [App Type].[Time Allocated]
FROM ([App Type] 
        INNER JOIN [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump] ON [App Type].AType = [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Type) 
        LEFT JOIN [Group Type] ON [App Type].Group = [Group Type].Group
WHERE [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Status ="T"
ORDER BY [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].[Pt Comp ID], [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Date
```

Thanks to Microsoft's lovely bits of inconsistency, the brackets have to be changed to back-quotes for Query Builder, so this is what I've put in there:

```
SELECT `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.`Pt Comp ID`, `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Date, 
       `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Gender, `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Age,
       `Group Type`.Description, Nz(`Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.`Pt Dept ID`,'EMPLOYEE') AS DeptID, `App Type`.Description AS `App Type`, `Group Type`.`Sort Order`, `App Type`.Provider, `App Type`.`Time Allocated`
  FROM `App Type` 
        INNER JOIN `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump` ON `App Type`.AType = `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Type
        LEFT JOIN `Group Type` ON `App Type`.Group = `Group Type`.Group
 WHERE `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Status ="T"
ORDER BY `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.`Pt Comp ID`, `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Date
```

And this is the error Query Builder returns:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '`App Type`.AType = `Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`.Type LEFT JOIN `Group Type`.Group = `Group Type`.Grou'.
```

Yes, the final "p" is missing from the end of the statement, I assume that's just a length limit on the error text, it is actually there in the code.

No, I don't know why the person who designed the DB put all those spaces in the table (and query) names, I'll have to look into removing them.

The query works just fine in Access, but doesn't even get to the point of running in query builder - what am I missing?

Comment: In the original query, there are brackets like `FROM ([App Type] ` and  `ON [App Type].AType = [Patient Stat Sched Data Dump].Type)` in the secound query these are missing. This might not be the error, I thought it is worth mentioning

Comment: Query Builder won't accept the brackets [], and requires the back-quote `` instead. If not, I wouldn't have gone to the effort of search/replace, and wouldn't have posted the same query with two different formats. Unless I've missed something, that is the only difference between the two

Comment: I meant the `()` not the `[]`

Comment: Access requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause for any query which includes more than one `JOIN`.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I misunderstood. When I adjust the FROM statement to read `FROM (``App Type`` INNER JOIN ``Patient Stat Sched Data Dump`` ON ``App Type``.AType = ``Patient Stat Sched Data Dump``.Type)
                   LEFT JOIN ``Group Type`` ON ``App Type``.Group = ``Group Type``.Group` which is exactly where the Access query has them, I get this message: `Could not add the table '(``App Type``'.` (NOTE: double `` are to escape the back-quote - otherwise the smart formatting makes it look really weird.)

Comment: Also, just for fun, I tried `FROM ([App Type] INNER JOIN...` and get a similar error `Could not add the table '([App'.` @Alex - Sorry, my response sounded really snippy... to me, brackets are square [], parenthesis are round (), and I didn't pay enough attention to what you'd quoted to notice the difference. HansUp's comment made me realize the difference.